# How to extract all the RAM card info on Linux?

Tags: memory

I have Kingston RAM and I plan to double the capacity

```
# dmidecode 3.0
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 3.0.0 present.

Handle 0x003D, DMI type 17, 40 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x003C
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 8192 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: DIMM_A1
    Bank Locator: BANK 0
    Type: DDR4
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 2133 MHz
    Manufacturer: Kingston
    Serial Number: 14236568
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
```

Do I have to buy the same Kingston card? Which are the minimum requirements for proper 2-card setup? I do not know much about hardware.

Comment: Get the serial number for the motherboard or computer.  Look up the proper details for what is supported by that hardware.

Comment: Check crucial.com to see what the specs of your board are once you've got the motherboard model.

Comment: No, you almost certainly don't need to get an exact match, but matching the speed and timings (note that DMI info does not show timing info, though your firmware setup program should if it's a reasonable MB) is a good idea for performance reasons.  Alternatively, buy a 2-pack of 4G sticks, use those, and keep the old one as a spare.